# Could any one say what is the my mistake in this regex

Tags: php, validation, url, preg-match

I want to use this regex for validating my urls in php with preg_match function but when i use it it says "Unknown modifier '&'"
what is the problem ?

```
$urlregex = "/^(http|ftp|https)\:\/\/";

        // USER AND PASS (optional)
        $urlregex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?";

        // HOSTNAME OR IP
        $urlregex .= "[a-z0-9+\$_-]+(\.[a-z0-9+\$_-]+)+"; // http://x.x = minimum

        // PORT (optional)
        $urlregex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?";
        // PATH (optional)
        $urlregex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?";
        // GET Query (optional)
        $urlregex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@/&%=+\$_.-]*)?";
        // ANCHOR (optional)
        $urlregex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?\$/";
        if(preg_match($urlregex, $url) === 1)
        {
            $errors[] = "URL_ISNOTVALID";
            $ok =  false;
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to escape a forward slash:

```
$urlregex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@/&%=+\$_.-]*)?";
```

should be

```
$urlregex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@\/&%=+\$_.-]*)?";
```

Comment: thanks @John , but now the code accept every thing as a url,is my regex correct for validationg url's?

Comment: A better way to do that is to use [`filter_var()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php). Much simpler.

Comment: i want to validate links with persian characters,Do you know what should i add to this code?

Comment: That I am unsure about. Do a quick search here and see if anyone has asked about that before. If not, that sounds like a great new question to me.

Comment: I search and nobody ask about persian urls validation

Answer (score 0):

The / (slash) in your GET Query is seen as the termination of the regex. And not the / at the end of your regex added in the ANCHOR line.

So you need to escape that / in front of the &.

```
    $urlregex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@/&%=+\$_.-]*)?";
```

bvecomes

```
    $urlregex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@\/&%=+\$_.-]*)?";
```

thats all.

Answer (score 0):

You could save some trouble by using `filter_var` instead.

```
if (false !== ($url = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))) {
    echo "$url is a valid url";
}
```

You can optionally add these options as the third parameter (use binary or to combine them):

- `FILTER_FLAG_PATH_REQUIRED`
- `FILTER_FLAG_QUERY_REQUIRED`